# PHP Extension:mysql in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

When I log into phpmyadmin it says that my PHP Extension is: MySQL.

I know this needs to be changed to mysqli but how do I do that? Is that something I can do myself or is it a server config setting that I need my web host to change?

Comment: Doesn't matter, just write code using the functions which begin with `mysqli_` rather than `mysql_`. Hopefully you are not using too old a version for you not to have mysqli support. `The mysqli extension was introduced with PHP version 5.0.0. The MySQL Native Driver was included in PHP version 5.3.0. `: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.installation.php

Comment: I am using mysqli in all my php code but I am getting this warning at the bottom of phpmyadmin: You are using PHP's deprecated 'mysql' extension, which is not capable of handling multi queries. <b>The execution of some stored routines may fail!</b> Please use the improved 'mysqli' extension to avoid any problems.  This is a factor as I am using stored procedures for one of my websites

Comment: But that warning is about phpMyAdmin's code not yours, os just don't worry.

Answer (score 8):

To instruct phpMyAdmin to use `mysqli` extension you have to add the following line to your `config.inc.php`

```
/* Select mysqli if your server has it */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
```

You can not change this setting from inside phpMyAdmin. You'll probably have to ask your web host to do that for you.

Comment: Also, it means that your host is running an older phpMyAdmin version, because the default extension used by phpMyAdmin has been switched to "mysqli" for more than two years.

Comment: No, it is the array of configuration. See this sample config file. https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/blob/master/config.sample.inc.php

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to upgrade to the latest version of PhpMyAdmin and PHP as well...

If want to upgrade php version to latest follow this link if you are on WAMP ->
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,113423,113435#msg-113435

If want to upgrade phpMyAdmin version to latest follow this link if you are on WAMP ->
http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,59446,59454

Hope this helps you.