# How do I IGNORE TABLE and Change ID in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

The following error message appeared after I installed a plugin on my website. I wonder what query to run in order to resolve this issue with MYSQL/PhpMyadmin?

> Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli_Exception: Mysqli prepare error: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near `` 'IGNORE TABLE
>   `xf_trophy_category` DROP PRIMARY KEY , CHANGE `trophy_category_id`' ``
>   at line 1 - library/Zend/Db/Statement/Mysqli.php:77

UPDATE.

This is the stack trace. I have asked the plugin developer but they are not working on it.

> ## 0 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Statement.php(115):
>
> Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli->_prepare('ALTER IGNORE TA...')
>
> ## 1 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Mysqli.php(381):
>
> Zend_Db_Statement->__construct(Object(Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli), 'ALTER
>   IGNORE TA...')
>
> ## 2 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(478):
>
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Mysqli->prepare('ALTER IGNORE TA...')
>
> ## 3 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/Waindigo/Install/20150313.php(758):
>
> Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER IGNORE TA...')
>
> ## 4 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/Waindigo/Install/20150313.php(216):
>
> Waindigo_Install->_makeTableChanges(Array)
>
> ## 5 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/Waindigo/Install/20150313.php(88):
>
> Waindigo_Install->_install(Array, Object(SimpleXMLElement))
>
> ## 6 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/XenForo/Model/AddOn.php(214):
>
> Waindigo_Install::install(false, Array, Object(SimpleXMLElement))
>
> ## 7 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/XenForo/Model/AddOn.php(169):
>
> XenForo_Model_AddOn->installAddOnXml(Object(SimpleXMLElement), false)
>
> ## 8 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/XenForo/ControllerAdmin/AddOn.php(188):
>
> XenForo_Model_AddOn->installAddOnXmlFromFile('/home/admin/tmp...')
>
> ## 9 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/XenForo/FrontController.php(351):
>
> XenForo_ControllerAdmin_AddOn->actionInstall()
>
> ## 10 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/XenForo/FrontController.php(134):
>
> XenForo_FrontController->dispatch(Object(XenForo_RouteMatch))
>
> ## 11 /home/admin/web/.com/public_html/admin.php(13): XenForo_FrontController->run()
>
> ## 12 {main}

Comment: Could you add the query that throws this error in the first place?

Comment: Probably something you need to ask the plugin developers. Are you sure your setup meets their minimum requirements?

Comment: Hi, I added the stack trace. Any suggestion to the problem would help. I appreciate all your help.

Comment: Are you really getting this error while running phpMyAdmin? It looks like an error message from some custom application, not the phpMyAdmin application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the plugin isn't compatible with MySQL 5.7, or whoever wrote the code is apparently unaware that `ALTER IGNORE` was deprecated in MySQL Server 5.6 and has been removed entirely in MySQL Server 5.7.  It was always a bad idea, because it facilitated sloppy database management.

> `IGNORE` is a MySQL extension to standard SQL. It controls how `ALTER TABLE` works if there are duplicates on unique keys in the new table or if warnings occur when strict mode is enabled. If `IGNORE` is not specified, the copy is aborted and rolled back if duplicate-key errors occur. If `IGNORE` is specified, only one row is used of rows with duplicates on a unique key. The other conflicting rows are deleted. Incorrect values are truncated to the closest matching acceptable value.
>
> As of MySQL 5.6.17, the `IGNORE` clause is deprecated and its use generates a warning. `IGNORE` is removed in MySQL 5.7.
>
> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html

The error refers to `the correct syntax to use near 'IGNORE ...'`, the server is telling you that `IGNORE` was encountered where it is not valid.  Everything before that was parsed correctly, and everything after that may be right or may be wrong, but this can't be determined since something unexpected was encountered.

If I am reading your stack trace correctly, it's here:

```
3 
/home/admin/web/.com/public_html/library/Waindigo/Install/20150313.php(758):
Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER IGNORE TA...')
```

Remove the word `IGNORE` from `Waindigo/Install/20150313.php` line 758 so that it starts `ALTER TABLE ...`.

Comment: Thank you very much. You were correct. I am using MySQL 5.7 and IGNORE became depreciated. I removed IGNORE from 'ALTER IGNORE TABLE' in 3 different lines in 20150313.php and the plugin installed fine. I want to you thank you for your time in helping me, I really appreciated it.

Answer (score 0):

If only a simple query would put things right, but in this case, I suspect that such a query is non-existent.  The good news is that the error is pointing to the software plugin as having a problem. While there might be a bug in the plugin, studying the error message closely suggests a more likely scenario: a software conflict.

The OP states that the current setup uses PHPMyAdmin with MySQL.  However, in the world of PHP, MySQL is now considered passe and users are urged to switch to MySQLi.  The plugin from Zend (ZendFramework possibly?) expects MySQLi apparently per the error it raises:

> Zend_Db_Statement_Mysqli_Exception: Mysqli prepare error:

Per this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19334688/php-extensionmysql-in-phpmyadmin), you may need to adjust your PHP config file as follows provided you have installed mysqli:

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';

Otherwise you probably just need to install MySQLi to make the plugin work correctly.

The requirements for xerforo mention:

> XenForo System Requirements 
>   PHP: 5.2.11+ 
>   MySQL: 5.0+ 
>   PHP extensions:
>   MySQLi, GD (with JPEG support), PCRE, SPL, SimpleXML, DOM, JSON,
>   iconv, ctype PHP safe_mode off

Lastly, you may wish to raise this issue with this [community](https://xenforo.com/community/).

Comment: This is the stack trace. I would ask the plugin developer but they have said they will not work on it.

Comment: Do you have MySQLi properly installed or are you still using MySQL?

Comment: Thank you, I had installed MySQLi but the issue was because I was using 5.7 instead of 5.6 MySQL and IGNORE became depreciated as explained by @Michael - sqlbot. Thank you for your help!